# Open office removing attached digital signature upon save

Tags: openoffice.org, digital-certificate

I have an open office ODT file (containing an X Form) with a digital certificate attached to it.

Now whenever a value is entered into a field in the X Form and a user tries to save the document he/she receives a prompt saying that the attached digital certificate will be removed if the document is saved. Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

The challenge is there are macro functions written which perform calculations based on the input fields. The digital certificate is used so that user can trust the macros.

So how to retain a digital certificate and allow the user to save the document???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the full document was signed, that signature will be lost on any alteration.

If the macros were independently signed, it takes a little more to figure out:

1. What version of OpenOffice.org was used to produce the .odt file and sign the macros only.
2. What version of OpenOffice.org are you using to modify the .odt file.

Comment: Open office version is 3.0.1
OOO300m15 (Build: 9379)

The version is the same for Creating the ODT file and modify the same.